# How history of posts are stored and how diffs are created

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, data-explorer

I like the way Stack Exchange presents diffs of (suggested) edits (or "posts" in general). At the moment I am experimenting with a webapp (with a relational DB in the backend) and I want to try to storing "posts" with history and presenting them to the user (with or without diff).

Since Stack Exchange also uses a relational DB (SQL Server) I would like to know how history or changes are stored and how the diffs are built from it.

I see 2 ways -

- storing it in dedicated history tables (I didn't find any hints [in the database schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede); there's no "diff" in "posthistory")
- using database-specific functions/logging/triggers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revisions for each post are stored in the `PostHistory` table. The full markdown text of each revision is stored in this table.

When viewing diffs, these are generated on the fly - we compare the two revisions and run the diff engine on them to produce the display.

Comment: thanks - "diff engine" is this an external library? Is field "text" the field that contains the body of the original post?

Comment: @dermoritz - The `Text` field is indeed the markdown body of the *revision* (a post can have several revisions).

Comment: The diff engine is not a third party library - it is a custom piece of code written for our particular needs.