# How are edits stored on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

When I want to edit the question/answer, or another user did, SO store the previous sentence that was deleted or modified, and will compare it with the new sentence or word. Did SO store all that edited/modified question/answer post into database? Even when I am trying to edit the question and answer many times (ex. 20 times). Does SO store all of that previous work into Database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> SO store the previous sentence that was deleted or modified

Not exactly. The entire text of older revisions is stored. When you view revisions, the modified text is highlighted (and non-modified may be truncated), but that is something that is done at the time of rendering, by an algorithm that highlights differences between two versions of a text.

> Even when I am trying to edit the question and answer many times (ex. 20 times).

When you make consecutive edits within 5 minutes, they will generally* be stored as one, that is, the later revision will replace the earlier one in the database. So, 20 edits in 5 minutes will not create 20 revisions.

(*) exception: if someone added a comment or an answer to a post, that particular revision (to which comment/answer was posted) will *not* be replaced by later edits, even if they happen shortly afterwards.

Comment: I have a supporting query in an answer of mine: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87224/how-does-so-store-revisions/297037#297037

Comment: @Desire , and what kind of algoritm did SO used?

Comment: @gagantous It's an in-house product; as an employee said, [it is a custom piece of code written for our particular needs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281905/how-history-of-posts-are-stored-and-how-diffs-are-created#comment915889_281906).  If you want to know how such things work in general, see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9065536) among many other search results.